# EF update entity without navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading, repository-pattern

I have the following entities with their relationships.

```
public class User {
    [Key]
    public int UserId {get;set;}

    ...
}


public class Profile {
    [Key]
    public int ProfileId {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public virtual User User {get;set;}
}
```

Now, when I want to update Profile, I retrieve it by ProfileId, apply my changes then call `SaveChanges()`.

Problem is that EF complains that the property `User` is required. I understand that EF doesn't load it when I retrieve Profile.

But How can I just update Profile, without affecting or loading User ?

Please also note that I'm using Generic Repository pattern, and would like to have a method in my `Repository<T>` to tell EF to ignore any given property if possible.

something like `MyRepository<T>.IgnorePropertyForUpdate(T entity, ??? property )`

Thanks In Adv.

Comment: Would it help if you include a property for the foreign key (`int UserId { get; set; }`)?

Comment: But I do need the One to One relationship to make sure that every profile has a User

Comment: Yeah, that won't change. To make it optional, you would need a `Nullable<int>` (and probably an annotation - sorry, it's been a while since I did EF). But if you have the foreign ID in there explicitly, as long at _that_ is set you can leave the navigation property set to null and updates etc will be performed based on the key value only.

Comment: Ah. right. Can you provide an example please ? I'm not sure how to setup ForeignKey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you dont have a Poco accessible FKid for User
EF knows User is required. you havent provided the record.
If you had declared the foreign key Id, ie userId
Then you would have the Id when saving.
EF can deal with the fact the whole record isnt there as long as the key is.

```
public class Profile {
[Key]
public int ProfileId {get;set;}


[Required]
[ForeignKey("User")] 
Public int UserId {get;set} 


public virtual User User {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Tried this. Still getting the same error "The User field is required."

Comment: What happens if you remove the `[Required]` tag from `User`? It is redundant because `UserId` is not nullable.

Comment: Actually, after playing around with your solution, I found that the `[Required]` can go in `UserId` to mention User is required. In that case, if the `UserId` is 0, EF throws and error when saving to say it is not set. (not matching User found in Users table) 
So.. Putting both attributes on `UserId` solved the issue. Please update the answer, I will mark as correct.

Comment: How do I do the same for collection ? Say my profile have `ICollection<Posts>`. How do I not load all the posts when I want to update ?

Answer (score 0):

The required annotation checks that the user must be loaded before you save the changes.It is a constraint in the database(**Database table Profile->Column(User) allow null = false**)
So you have to include the user in your Profile entity in the repository for example if you are using Daynmic library `MyUserRepository.Include("User");`

If you are doing that directly you can do like that:

```
context.Prfiles.Include(p => p.User)....ToList();
```

Comment: I don't want to load the user just to update the profile. So how do I tell EF that the User is not changed so it doesn't need to update that ?

Comment: In this case you need to use Detached objects in entity framework and no Tacking this is a big constructor and I do not recommand it you to do that.